# Getting undefined reference to 'clock_gettime' error, for curl program

Tags: c, curl, libcurl, cross-compiling

Gretings,

I have cross compile, OpenSSl , libssh2 and finally cURL, Don't know why it has generated only static library. Anyway I tried to run sample ftpget.c program by linking all the three libraries but I am getting the following error :

```
.../libcurl.a(timeval.o): In function 'curlx_tvnow':
timeval.c:(.text+0xfc): undefined reference to 'clock_gettime'
collect2: ld return  1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Please help me resolve this error, Is there need to cross-compile any other library also ?

Thanks,
Yuvi

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try linking with librt (`-lrt`).

Comment: @Yuvi: Cross-compile?  I'm assuming that you're running on Linux; librt should always be available (I hope!).

Answer (score 3):

You need to link with the real-time library.
Use `-lrt`

```
gcc ... -lrt ...
```

Comment: I am cross compiling for arm,